# Reset styles on given element, but preserve HTML Attribute stylings

Tags: html, css, attributes, w3c

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove all styles on a given element (Using all: intial; (or something)), while still preserving the HTML attribute stylings?

Example:

```html
<table bgcolor="#D9D9D9">
  .. Etc
</table>
```

This would obviously set BG Color to that color, however in my case bootstrap overrides the background color of tables.

So now, I want to remove the bootstrap override on that specific element, while still I want to preserve the HTML Attribute style so it would become that color.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML attributes of specific style property are outdated and not recommended now. Correct way to solve bootstrap override is using style attribute.

```
<table style="background-color: #D9D9D9;">
  .. Etc
</table>
```

if you need to force style - can use **!important**

```
<table style="background-color: #D9D9D9 !important;">
  .. Etc
</table>
```

To override bootstrap properties, you have to load personal CSS document after bootstrap with all styles you need to override.